# Are C++ arithmetic operations between different types of integers cost free?

Tags: c++

I have a project that needs more speed and less memory consumption, so I learned about `int_fast_t` and started to use it.

In the meantime, I have the following question about it:
 Do C++ arithmetic operations between different types of integers require an implicit cast or the like, or are they cost-free?

Another way to ask, is `int_fast8_t + int_fast32_t`, for example, slower than `int + int`? Why?

Comment: Your two questions are a bit different. It is logically possible for there to be additional overhead when adding `int_fast8_t` to `int_fast32_t` yet still have that operation be faster than adding two `int`s.

Comment: "I have a project that needs more speed " and you're sure the performance bottleneck is integer arithmetic?

Comment: If you have to ask, then you don't know your hardware. If you don't know your hardware, you should not be trying to do such optimizations, for it is very likely you do it wrong, assuming what you do has any impact whatsoever (example: if you are writing code for x86 or amd64, what you are doing is useless).

Answer (score 1):

The rules for arithmetic operations in C++ are rather nuts.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion contains them.

But conversion up to `int`/`unsigned int` is logically done on every operation.

The result is then converted back on assignment.

This logical conversion does not have to happen in actual machine code, so 8 bit ints can be done in 8 bit hardware, so long as the results of converting to int then back to 8 bit is the same; and that can be faster.  On other systems, that could be costly, and fast 8 int is 32 bits in size.

Answer (score 1):

The performance is entirely implementation-dependent. In one implementation, converting `int_fast8_t` to `int_fast32_t` might involve overhead, and adding an `int_fast8_t` to an `int_fast32_t` might be slower than adding two `int`s in some circumstances.

In another implementation, however, it might be that each of `int_fast8_t`, `int_fast32_t`, and `int` are the same 32-bit signed integers. In this case, there would be no conversion, and the adding of values of any combination of these types would be equally fast.

Perhaps the biggest consideration to keep in mind is that the `int_fastN_t` types are not intrinsically faster than other integer types. They merely give the compiler the option to use more bits than requested if that could give a performance boost. Perhaps accessing a single byte from memory takes an extra instruction, so a 16-bit value can be processed faster than an 8-bit value can. If that's the case, `int_fast8_t` might be a typedef of `short`. You are not getting better performance than a `short`; the only promise being made is that using `int_fast8_t` is at least as fast as using `unsigned char`.

Another example: On today's computers, `int_fast64_t` is likely a `typedef` (or equivalent) of `long long`. Same type, no performance difference. Use the `int_fastN_t` types if you are more concerned with speed than size, but don't assume you will actually see a speed boost – you might already be at optimal performance.